# array_agg on multiple columns by one column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I currently have an example tagging table like this:

```
id | tag    | user_id | video_id
 1 | cake   |       1 |        1
 2 | cookie |       1 |        2
 3 | crab   |       2 |        2
 4 | carrot |       2 |        2
```

I'd like to group the most recent 10-20 rows by the video_id, with the other columns as arrays:

```
video_id 1, has tag "cake", user_id 1
video_id 2, has tags "cookie", "cake", "crab", by user_id 1, user_id 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT video_id, array_agg(tag) as tags, array_agg(user_id) as user_ids
FROM tags
ORDER BY id
GROUP BY video_id
LIMIT 10
```